# Merge multiple dataframes while retaining their names as column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, r-colnames

I'm trying to import multiple CSV files in the RStudio while keeping their filenames.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

#importing all csv files at once
csv_files = list.files(pattern ="*Con.csv")
myfiles = lapply(csv_files , read.delim, header = TRUE, sep = "," )

#merging all files by identifiers
Samp_merg <- myfiles %>% reduce(full_join, by=c("chr", "start","end"))
```

After doing this I could import the files but the names of the files were missing from the list `myfiles`.

```
myfiles <- dir(pattern = "*Con.csv", full.names = FALSE) 
myfiles_data <- lapply(myfiles, data.table::fread) 

# assign names to list items
names(myfiles_data) <- myfiles 

#merging the files
dat_merg <- myfiles_data %>% reduce(full_join, by=c("chr", "start", "end"))
```

Here, using this script I can import the files by keeping their names in the `myfiles_data` object. However, after joining by three identifiers I'm unable to retain their file names as column names. I want to keep the `colname` of the merged `df` as the individual file name without extension (.csv).

There are around 90 CSV files present in the directory with the same header.

```
$ls
01AvPMPpCon.csv
02AvPMPpCon.csv
03AvPMPpCon.csv
04AvPMPpCon.csv
05AvPMPpCon.csv

$head 01AvPMPpCon.csv 
chr,start,end,CpG
chr1,2017424,2017750,10
chr1,24901325,24901700,11
chr1,24902268,24902701,25
chr1,24927215,24927416,4
chr1,26861926,26862173,5
chr1,26864186,26864613,15
chr1,35576334,35576451,3
chr1,36304606,36304817,7
```

At now, the merged file looks like this,

```
$head(dat_merg)
    chr    start      end CpG.x CpG.y CpG.x.x CpG.y.y CpG.x.x.x CpG.y.y.y
1: chr1  3903250  3903277     4    NA      NA      NA         4        NA
2: chr1  4657240  4657314     3    NA      NA      NA        NA        NA
3: chr1 24900249 24900468     5    NA       5      NA        NA        NA
4: chr1 46484938 46485047     4    NA       4      NA        NA        NA
5: chr1 47223634 47223758     4    NA      NA      NA         4         4
6: chr1 66752822 66753167    12    12      NA      NA        12        NA
```

So, my expected output should look like,

```
 $head(dat_merg)
        chr    start      end   01Av  02Av    03Av    04Av      05Av      06Av
    1: chr1  3903250  3903277     4    NA      NA      NA         4        NA
    2: chr1  4657240  4657314     3    NA      NA      NA        NA        NA
    3: chr1 24900249 24900468     5    NA       5      NA        NA        NA
    4: chr1 46484938 46485047     4    NA       4      NA        NA        NA
    5: chr1 47223634 47223758     4    NA      NA      NA         4         4
    6: chr1 66752822 66753167    12    12      NA      NA        12        NA
```

Comment: ```myfiles_data %>%  imap(function(x, y) x %>% rename_with(~paste0(y, .), -c("chr", "start", "end")) %>%  reduce(full_join, by = c("chr", "start", "end"))```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your advice. I think something is missing here,
`merge_df<-myfiles_data %>%  imap(function(x, y) x 
             %>% rename_with(~paste0(y, .), -c("chr", "start", "end")) 
             %>% reduce(full_join, by = c("chr", "start", "end")))`
After using this, what  I got,
`Error in 'map2()':
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: 01AvPMPpCon.csv.
Caused by error in 'UseMethod()':
! no applicable method for 'full_join' applied to an object of class "character"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `pivot_wider()` instead of `reduce(full_join, ...)`?

Prepare reprex, 99 4-row csv files:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

csv_ <- read_csv("chr,start,end,CpG
chr1,2017424,2017750,10
chr1,24901325,24901700,11
chr1,24902268,24902701,25
chr1,24927215,24927416,4
chr1,26861926,26862173,5
chr1,26864186,26864613,15
chr1,35576334,35576451,3
chr1,36304606,36304817,7", show_col_types = FALSE)

sprintf("%.2dAvPMPpCon.csv", 1:99) |>
  walk(\(f_) slice_sample(csv_, n = 4) |> write_csv(f_))
```

`read_csv()` can read from a list of files and stores file names in *id* column, `c(chr, start, end)` will be used for `pivot_wider()` `id_cols` :

```r
list.files(pattern ="*Con.csv") |>
  read_csv(id = "src") |>
  mutate(src = substr(src, 1, 4)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = src, values_from = CpG)
#> Rows: 396 Columns: 5
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (1): chr
#> dbl (3): start, end, CpG
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
```

Result:

```r
#> # A tibble: 8 × 102
#>   chr      start     end `01Av` `02Av` `03Av` `04Av` `05Av` `06Av` `07Av` `08Av`
#>   <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 chr1  26864186  2.69e7     15     NA     15     15     NA     NA     NA     NA
#> 2 chr1  26861926  2.69e7      5      5     NA      5      5     NA     NA     NA
#> 3 chr1  24902268  2.49e7     25     25     25     25     25     25     NA     NA
#> 4 chr1  24927215  2.49e7      4      4     NA     NA      4     NA      4      4
#> 5 chr1  35576334  3.56e7     NA      3      3     NA     NA      3      3     NA
#> 6 chr1   2017424  2.02e6     NA     NA     10     10     NA     NA     10     10
#> 7 chr1  24901325  2.49e7     NA     NA     NA     NA     11     11     11     11
#> 8 chr1  36304606  3.63e7     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      7     NA      7
#> # ℹ 91 more variables: `09Av` <dbl>, `10Av` <dbl>, `11Av` <dbl>, `12Av` <dbl>,
#> #   `13Av` <dbl>, `14Av` <dbl>, `15Av` <dbl>, `16Av` <dbl>, `17Av` <dbl>,
#> #   `18Av` <dbl>, `19Av` <dbl>, `20Av` <dbl>, `21Av` <dbl>, `22Av` <dbl>,
#> #   `23Av` <dbl>, `24Av` <dbl>, `25Av` <dbl>, `26Av` <dbl>, `27Av` <dbl>,
#> #   `28Av` <dbl>, `29Av` <dbl>, `30Av` <dbl>, `31Av` <dbl>, `32Av` <dbl>,
#> #   `33Av` <dbl>, `34Av` <dbl>, `35Av` <dbl>, `36Av` <dbl>, `37Av` <dbl>,
#> #   `38Av` <dbl>, `39Av` <dbl>, `40Av` <dbl>, `41Av` <dbl>, `42Av` <dbl>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
## libraries

library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
```

```
## sample data (credit to margusl)

csv_ <- read_csv("
chr , start,    end,      CpG
chr1, 2017424,  2017750,  10
chr1, 24901325, 24901700, 11
chr1, 24902268, 24902701, 25
chr1, 24927215, 24927416, 4
chr1, 26861926, 26862173, 5
chr1, 26864186, 26864613, 15
chr1, 35576334, 35576451, 3
chr1, 36304606, 36304817, 7", 
show_col_types = FALSE)

set.seed(123)
sprintf("%.2dAvPMPpCon.csv", 1:3) |>
  walk(\(f_) slice_sample(csv_, n = 4) |> write_csv(f_))
```

```
## import and pre-process

# importing all csv files at once
myfiles = lapply(list.files(pattern ="*Con.csv"), 
                 read.delim, 
                 header = TRUE, sep = "," )

# set the names (removing "PMPpCon.csv" and only keeping "##Av" part)
names(myfiles) <- gsub("PMPpCon.csv", "", csv_files)
```

```
## solution

# renaming the columns and appending the dataframe name prior to joining
myfiles %>%  
  imap(function(x, y) x %>% 
         rename_with(~paste(y, ., sep = "_"), 
                     -c("chr", "start", "end"))) %>%  
  reduce(full_join, by = c("chr", "start", "end"))
```

```
## results

#>    chr    start      end 01Av_CpG 02Av_CpG 03Av_CpG
#> 1 chr1 35576334 35576451        3       NA       NA
#> 2 chr1 36304606 36304817        7        7       NA
#> 3 chr1 24902268 24902701       25       25       NA
#> 4 chr1 26864186 26864613       15       15       15
#> 5 chr1 24901325 24901700       NA       11       NA
#> 6 chr1 26861926 26862173       NA       NA        5
#> 7 chr1 24927215 24927416       NA       NA        4
#> 8 chr1  2017424  2017750       NA       NA       10
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>